# How do you multiply Decimals keeping the same decimal_places

Tags: python, python-3.x

Wednesday Woahs - Trying to learn ‘simple’ arithmetic using Decimals

```
>>> a = Decimal('100.00')
>>> a
Decimal('100.00')
>>> b = Decimal('4.00')
>>> b
Decimal('4.00')
>>> a + b
Decimal('104.00')
>>> a * b
Decimal('400.0000')
```

How do you multiply Decimals with 2 decimal_places that keeps/rounds/limits to 2 places?   (`4.00 * 100.00` => `400.0000` [ie 4 decimal places instead of 2])

I am trying to count money, taxes, subtotals, lineitems, etc…   Just some basic accounting arithmetic.  Here are some inputs and expected outputs:

```
4.00 * 100.00 => 400.00
0.01 * 0.01 => 0.00
1.00 * 0.07 => 0.07
1.00 * 0.075 => 0.08 (im not sure I may have a use case for that, but Im sure it could be chained/curried to get that [ie `a = 7.50 / 100` then `100.00 * a` => `0.08`])
```

I'm not sure if this is called precision error, creep, or what….

Comment: What output do you want if you multiply `Decimal('0.01')` by itself?

Comment: I guess I'm fine with `0.00` :)   I'm unaware if there are different outputs based on different solutions.

Comment: I would say something about `decimal` not doing significance arithmetic, but your expectations don't actually match significance arithmetic either. You seem to just want to round everything to the nearest multiple of 0.01, which is kind of weird.

Comment: Think of it in the fact that Im counting money, which should not be that weird.  Ill update the question to provide some more context

Comment: Even in the context of money, you'd want different handling for money and not-money quantities. It doesn't make sense to multiply 104 dollars by 400 dollars. It *does* make sense to multiply 104 dollars by 0.0725 sales tax, even though 0.0725 would involve sub-penny values if it was a dollar quantity. Also, sub-penny price increments are a thing.

Comment: Your second case is what I would be doing.  along with 4 units of 100 each unit (or similar)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the decimal place of a Decimal by using `quantize()`.

For example

```
>>> d = Decimal(123.456789)
>>> d.quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
Decimal('123.46')
```

For example in your case, you can do

```
c = (a*b).quantize(Decimal('0.01'))
# or 
c = (a*b).quantize(a)    # c will be in same exponent as a
# or, depending your preference in style
c = getcontext().quantize( a*b, Decimal('0.01'))
```